# Access Violation during MFC execution of CFrameWnd::InitialUpdateFrame

Tags: c++, mfc

I am in the process of trying to upgrade a VC++ 6.0 project to the latest version and am running into an issue. The program starts up fine but in the process of creating two child windows within the main view it crashes with an access violation. When run in debug mode it cannot find the exact location where the error occurs, displaying "Frame not in module" and "The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location" making it difficult to pinpoint the exact issue.

Going through the program step by step reveals that the error lies in the call of
`CFrameWnd::InitialUpdateFrame.`

From there it goes into the following functions:
Main.cpp:

```
frame->InitialUpdateFrame(dc, TRUE);
```

winfrm.cpp:

```
SendMessageToDescendants(WM_INITIALUPDATE, 0, 0, TRUE, TRUE);
```

afxwin2.inl:

```
CWnd::SendMessageToDescendants(m_hWnd, message, wParam, lParam, bDeep, bOnlyPerm);
```

wincore.cpp:

```
SendMessageToDescendants(hWndChild, message, wParam, lParam, bDeep, bOnlyPerm);
```

(Recursion to same function, error occurs on second recursion)

wincore.cpp:

```
AfxCallWndProc(pWnd, pWnd->m_hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
```

Error has occurred at 3 of the following locations:
wincore.cpp:

```
_AfxPreInitDialog(pWnd, &rectOld, &dwStyle);

lResult = pWnd->WindowProc(nMsg, wParam, lParam);

_AfxPostInitDialog(pWnd, rectOld, dwStyle);
```

It is called from this function (simplified):

```
CDocument* XApp::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName) 
{


    doc_x_spc *dc = 
            static_cast<doc_x_spc *> ( m_spc_template->CreateNewDocument() );

    CMDIChildWnd *frame = 
        static_cast<CMDIChildWnd *> ( m_spc_template->CreateNewFrame(dc, NULL) );

    if ( !dc->OnOpenDocument(lpszFileName) )
    {
        AfxMessageBox( IDS_SPCOPENERROR, MB_OK, NULL );

        return NULL;
    }

    CString raw(lpszFileName);
    dc->set_raw_file(raw);

    frame->InitialUpdateFrame(dc, TRUE);
    
    if (app_multiplexed == SINGLE)
        menu.LoadMenu(IDR_REMPLETYPE_SINGLE);
    else
        menu.LoadMenu(IDR_REMPLETYPE);

    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = (CMainFrame *)m_pMainWnd;

    pMainFrame->MDISetMenu(&menu, NULL);
    
    return dc;
}
```

The access violation produces this exact error:
`Exception thrown at 0x01144008 in X.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x01144008.`

Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Did you build with _DEBUG defined? Do a debug build, run under the debugger, and it should point you to the exact line that has the problem

Comment: If you cannot find the faulting instruction in a debug configuration, then run the release build under a debugger. Alternatively, [set up WER to collect user-mode dumps on crash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) for offline analysis. You can load the dump in any Windows debugger (like Visual Studio). Since the AV appears to be originating from generated code, you might want to give [time travel debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-walkthrough) a go.